# Use the same footnote for different entries in a table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have the following code (I am using Overleaf):

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\caption{Text text text}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{rccl}
Parameter & x & y & z \footnote{Footnote 1} \\
\colrule
$a_1$ & 1  & 2 & 10 \footnote{\label{note2} Footnote 2} \\
$b_1$ & 3   & 4  & 20 \footnote{\label{note3} Footnote 3}\\
 \\
\colrule
$a_2$ & 5   & 6 &  30 \footnotemark[\ref{note2}] \\
$b_2$ & 7   & 8 & 40 \footnotemark[\ref{note3}] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the output is in the figure below. In this simple example I want the footnotes b and c to be associated to different entries in the table. However, it seems like the second time I try to use them, they don't appear as superscripts anymore. Moreover, the footnote a entry seems to be shifted relative to the b and c. How can I fix this and have proper superscripts for all footnotes and well aligned footnotes? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: There is a space between `b`/`c` as you have a space in your `\footnote{\label{note2} Footnote 2}`, change it to `\footnote{\label{note2}Footnote 2}` and it should get rid of the space. For the other question, you could always do `30 \textsuperscript{b}` to make it look the same.

Answer (score 2):

The [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package and its eponymous environment are your friends. The package also provides the `\tnote` macro and the `tablenotes` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit} % optional: footnote markers in italics

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Text text text}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
Parameter & x & y &  z\tnote{a} \\
\colrule
$a_1$     & 1 & 2 & 10\tnote{b} \\
$b_1$     & 3 & 4 & 20\tnote{c} \\
\colrule
$a_2$     & 5 & 6 & 30\tnote{b} \\
$b_2$     & 7 & 8 & 40\tnote{c} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}

\smallskip\scriptsize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Footnote 1
\item[b] Footnote 2
\item[c] Footnote 3
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you get some errors in your document, when those come you should not ignore them and cannot rely on your PDF being correct.  But I think you are looking for `\footref`.

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Text text text}
  \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{rccl}
      Parameter & x & y & z \footnote{Footnote 1} \\
      \colrule
      $a_1$ & 1  & 2 & 10 \footnote{\label{note2}Footnote 2} \\
      $b_1$ & 3   & 4  & 20 \footnote{\label{note3}Footnote 3}\\
      \\
      \colrule
      $a_2$ & 5   & 6 &  30 \footref{note2} \\
      $b_2$ & 7   & 8 & 40 \footref{note3} \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]